# A Textbook Problem, Slightly Modified

Tags: geometry, euclidean-domain

The following is an image of a math problem I am trying to solve. It was originally a textbook problem (*given O, P, Q are midpoints of CD, CB, and DA respectively and CM=CN and ∠COA=∠DOB, prove AD=CB, a trivial SAS congruence problem.*) I changed the information into the following:

### Given

- P is the midpoint of AO
- Q is the midpoint of BO
- O is the midpoint of CD
- CP = QD
- ∠COA = ∠DOB

### Prove

- BC = AD
- AO = OB

### What I have done

I have tried to prove ∆AOD is congruent to ∆BOC, but that is unfortunately SSA, which is famous for not being true.

I have succeeded in proving AB//PQ, but don't know what to do next.

Our class has only studied parallel lines and congruence and the sum of interior angles of a triangle being 180 degrees so if it is possible please do not use similarity or something clearly out of scope (for instance, trigonometry or the Cartesian Plane). Or, please tell me why I can't prove this. PAA (Partial Answers Appreciated).

[image: 1]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Why is most of your text in bold?

Comment: To unhighlight part of the text. Is there a better method, @JoséCarlosSantos? Thanks

Comment: I think that you are overusing putting characters in bold.

Comment: Quote, Is there a better method? @JoséCarlosSantos

Comment: I suppose ECA must be changed to CDA ? There is no E point in picture and problem statement

Comment: Whoops, when I renamed the point labels I messed things up, @IvanKaznacheyeu. Sorry.

Comment: I suppose solution can be done easy using vectors. $\vec{CP}=\frac{2\vec{CA}+\vec{CD}}{4}$

Comment: Oh no, that's a little too hard for me (just kidding, i understand vectors, but i'm thinking of a geometric approach. FYI I'm a seventh-grader) @IvanKaznacheyeu

Comment: What about this construction https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DCNv.png

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu $AQD$ should be on the same line, as well as $BPC$.

Comment: There is no indication of this fact in textual problem statement.

Comment: Please, don't make me add what is obvious. I didn't even state A is a point.

Comment: In the problem statement (Given) P is defined as middle of AO and there is no fact that P is in line BC. If this fact is not given, then claim is wrong.

Comment: If you add in Given the facts that P is in line BC and Q is in line AD, then you don't need CP=QD to prove the claim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure whether you know [Menelaus's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menelaus%27s_theorem) (the spelling is copied from wiki, which I find wierd).

Applying Menelaus to the triangle $AOD$ and the line $BC$, we get $\frac{AX}{XD} = \frac 12$. Similarly, $\frac{BX}{XC} = \frac 12$. These tell us that $AB$ is parallel to $CD$.

On the other hand, $\frac{OP}{PA} = 1 = \frac{OQ}{QB}$ which tells us that $PQ$ is parallel to $AB$.

Hence $PQ$ is parallel to $CD$. Together with $CP = QD$, we see that $CPQD$ is an isosceles trapezoid and everything else is clear.

Comment: Yes indeed, and I sent my proof of the Menelaus's theorem to my teacher :-). Thanks. Oh, and can you help me prove PQ is parallel to AB? Thank you... I find it a bit painful, given I don't want to introduce similar triangles.